# 'r' rendered improperly in Devanagari ligature

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures, indic

Have bumped into a LaTeX-specific problem (on my current system at least) in typesetting Devanagari: 'r' in conjunct consonants such as 'ntrya' does not render properly (e.g., as न्त्र्य, see image below) for me using xelatex.  It has rendered properly in the past, so I'm not sure what's going on. I've looked at fontspec and tried various fonts, and the problem doesn't appear in Libreoffice (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, using texlive 2011). Sure I must be missing something silly. Here's a mwe,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={5in,3in},total={4in,2in}}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily\latinfont[Script=Latin,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newcommand\eng[1]{\latinfont #1}
\begin{document}
{\huge मन्त्र्यमाण \eng{--- This is not what 

\bigskip

“mantryamāṇa” should look like!}} 
\end{document}
```

which produces the image below on my machine:

[image]

Does anyone know why I'm getting this alternate form and how I can switch to the expected 'r' form?

---

Based on Jamadagni's feedback, I upgraded to TeXLive 2012 and the problem has disappeared.

Comment: After some digging, I found that this problem is discussed in this XeTeX Mailing List Archive thread (http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2012-June/023192.html), with some of the opinion that this bug (http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/65/) is the culprit. From what I can tell, this is an ongoing bug specific to XeTeX, for which there is no solution at present. If anyone knows of one, please do let us know.

Comment: Thanks Speravir ;).  @Jamadagni's feedback gave me hope that an upgrade would solve the issue and it has.  After upgrading, my conjunct characters display properly.  I'll update the post so that the solution is clear to others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that "Do others get the same output" is a question for StackExchange -- rather it is for the XeTeX mailing list, but anyhow, I just compiled your tex file using XeLaTeX from the TeXLive 2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1 package from the PPA on Kubuntu Precise and I get the correct rendering as you can see:

[image]

Comment: I agree, this needs to be taken up with the XeTeX list. I'll do so and update this post accordingly for others who run into the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I've also edited the post lest anyone think that my question regarding others' output was the problem for which this post desires a solution.