# Problem with r- ligatures in XeTeX (with the font Sanskrit 2003)

Tags: fonts, xetex, ligatures, indic

Simple ligatures with र् r as first element (thus a case different from ['r' rendered improperly in Devanagari ligature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88323/r-rendered-improperly-in-devanagari-ligature) ) appear strangely when preceded by a syllable containing an ि : I appears that the ि "attracts" the र r, as can be seen in the screenshot, produced from the simple code below. I just put a nonsense word kikarta, which is displayed in something looking like "rkikata"

This problem can be solve if something like `\vphantom{x}` is inserted before the र्त rta, but this solution is not viable. Has anybody an idea of how to solve this  issue?

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}

\begin{document} 

किकर्त    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but to be able to show some pictures ...

I get with this example the following outputs on windows. So it could be that there is bug in the miktex xelatex. But I don't know if you are using it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}
\setsansfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\begin{document}

किकर्त \sffamily किकर्त 

\end{document}
```

### xelatex from TeXLive 2015 and 2014

[image]

### xelatex from MikTeX

[image]

### lualatex (both)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I indeed use MixTeK, and I see it works well with the Nakula font, it will try this one instead. However, I think that fixing this bug might be useful, do you know whom I could contact to mention it?

Comment: I put a bug report on the miktex site: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2382/.